# How to render content outside of drupal instance

Tags: drupal-7

i created one website using drupal. In Drupal i crated content pages in that instance using wisywig editor. now my intention is using this content block outside of drupal. can you anyone  please help me how to use this content block outside of drupal (with code or something else).

i mean how to render content outside of drupal instance

Comment: I guess just perfrom a mysql query on the tables that contain drupal content.  You'll be responsible for "rendering" that data, though.

Answer (score 0):

Rendering blocks and nodes is straight-forward.

Before you can do either you must initiate the drupal core:

```
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
```

Using `getcwd()` assumes you are placing the script in drupal's root.

To display blocks, use [`block_load()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.module/function/block_load/7):

```
$blocks[] = block_load('block',$delta); //first block to display
$blocks[] = block_load('block',$delta2); //second block to display
print drupal_render(_block_get_renderable_array(_block_render_blocks($blocks)));
```

For nodes, there are several approaches. [`node_view(`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_view/7)[`node_load()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_load/7)`)` seems to be the cleanest:

```
print drupal_render(node_view(node_load($nodeId)));
```